# Setting Folder for Data pgfplots in LyX

Tags: pgfplots, lyx, external-files

I'm trying to get a figure in my LaTeX document, but I struggle to set the search-path

I use

```
\addplot[blue] table {invcum.dat};
```

from the example, however it keeps saying

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'invcum.dat'.
```

After trying around with various things I looked at the reportings from Process Monitor (Sysinternals) and it shows, that the file is only looked for in the temporary directory.

In LyX I found the TEXINPUT option and it was set to "." I added my working directory to it (where the data file lies) but I keep getting the same behaviour.

I will continue by inserting the data into the documents directly, but I'd really like to see what I missed to get things working.

Comment: As a workaround, does it work if you set the full path to invcum.dat?

Comment: I would have expected `TEXINPUTS` instead of `TEXINPUT`. Maybe it was just a typo? Note that `pgfplots` supports an option called `table/search path` as of version 1.13